# closing timer in blackberry

Tags: java, blackberry

I am developing an application for blackberry. I have a timer, when I declare it as static & close the timer after certain interval, it works. If i don't declare the timer as static and call `timer.cancel()`, the timer is not closed. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

At a wild guess I would say you are closing the timer from a different instance of the class it is part of. When it's static they are the same timer. When it isn't, it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

You can  cancel the `timeSchedule`  for the `TimerTask()`, by  calling the  method  `cancel();`